WTelegramClient CHAT_FORWARDS_RESTRICTED
I want to fetch messages from one channel and forward them to my own channel, but I'm getting a CHAT FORWARDS RESTRICTED error. Can't I bypass this?
var History = await Client.Messages_GetHistory(Target.Channel, limit:ID);
foreach (dynamic Message in History.Messages)
{
    await Client.SendMessageAsync(Your.Channel, Message?.message, Message?.media?.ToInputMedia(), entities:Message?.entities);
}


If message.media?.ToInputMedia() leads to CHAT_FORWARDS_RESTRICTED, there's not much you can do except download the media & reupload it.
You can detect such protected messages/channel via the flags.HasFlag(Flags.noforwards) on Message or Channel objects
